# jQuery $.getJSON() Fails

Tags: jquery, jsonp, getjson

I keep getting errors using $.getJSON(). I'm using JSONP. Here's the code:

```
$.getJSON('http://s3.amazonaws.com/eloqu/TestFile.js?callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + textStatus + ', ' + error);
});
```

All I get is a 'parsererror'. If i change the end of the url to callback=mycallback, I just get 'error', without the type.

Comment: try to output `error`in your fail handler. the second `?`in your url probably needs escaping to `%3f`.

Comment: what is the json you are returning? Is it wrapped in a `mycallback` function?

Comment: @James You're using `$.getJSON()`, which is `json`, not `jsonp` You'll probably need to use `$.ajax` and set the `dataType` to `jsonp`.

Comment: Escaping the second question mark fixed my parser error, but it still doesn't work. The error is still blank.

You can see the JSON from that URL.

Comment: @JasonP According to the jQuery docs, it should interpret any url with a callback parameter as JSONP. Their Flickr example uses it.

Comment: We have two James talking here.  Very confusing.  what does your Testfile.js script output?

Comment: The URL is valid. it is just: mycallback({ "test": "variable", "test2": "variable2" })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd situation...

Here's a working fiddle.. I had to define the `mycallback` function:

http://jsfiddle.net/xtKAb/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://s3.amazonaws.com/eloqu/TestFile.js?callback=?');
});

function mycallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

I think the problem is that the remote file is static. Generally, you send the callback you want, and the remote service wraps the data in the callback you specify. Here's an example of the actual request jQuery makes:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/eloqu/TestFile.js?callback=jQuery20209767435337416828_1376014401926&_=1376014401927
```

So jQuery is expecting the callback to be `jQuery20209767435337416828_1376014401926()`, but that doesn't happen (because the remote file is static). Since the data doesn't get to the callback that jQuery is expecting, it most likely tries to json parse an undefined object, which is giving you the parse error.

Answer (score 0):

Your return looks like this :

```
mycallback({ "test": "variable", "test2": "variable2" })
```

while a valid json would be:

```
{ "test": "variable", "test2": "variable2" }
```

A valid json can only start with an array sign [ or an object sign {
you can validate any json string on http://jsonlint.com

Comment: I'm using JSONP because this is a cross-domain request.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed this was jsonp